# python-pptx saving chart as a image file?

Tags: python-3.x, image, python-pptx

I'm looking for a way to save chart made with python-pptx as a image file such as jpeg. I'm trying to make a automation from making charts with data and then put those chart in another word processing program or web page.

I have tried to search a way to do this, but all I found was copying whole slides, or cropping the screen, which I don't prefer since it can hurt the resolution.

Sorry that I couldn't try any code that I've found since it doesn't fit in my case.

Any documentation or reference recommendation is welcomed as well!

Thanks and have a nice day(weekend)

Comment: VBA might be a better bet. python-pptx doesn't do rendering so can't do this.